# Blaze LoginButtons Template Rendered in React - Login Only Works on Homepage

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, authentication, meteor-blaze

So I am using Meteor/React, but I used Blaze's login template for its convenience. It works great on the homepage, but when I try to login from any other page on the site, the page reloads and the login appears to have been unsuccessful.

This is my implementation.

AccountsUI.jsx

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class AccountsUI extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        this.view = Blaze.render(Template.loginButtons, this.refs.loginContainer);

    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        Blaze.remove(this.view);
    }

    render(){
        return(

            <span ref="loginContainer" />

        )
    }

}
```

mainLayout.jsx

```
  <div className="container-fluid">
                <a className="navbar-btn pull-left panel-body"><b>FAQ</b></a>

                <a className="navbar-btn pull-right panel-body"><b>Category</b></a>
                <a className="navbar-btn pull-right panel-body"><b>Notifications</b></a>
                <a className="navbar-btn pull-right panel-body"><b><AccountsUI /></b></a>

            </div>
        </div>
```

Why would this work only on certain pages?

Answer (score 2):

### **Blaze**

Your code looks ok, are you importing all components correctly?

Try: https://atmospherejs.com/gadicc/blaze-react-component

and do:

```
import Blaze from 'meteor/gadicc:blaze-react-component';

....

<a className="navbar-btn pull-right panel-body"><b><Blaze template="loginButtons" /></b></a>

....
```

Without trying to change your choice of tools too much, I have been exploring React, Meteor and Authentication for a little while, often getting stuck in state management and other dark holes. Below is a overview of some options:

### **React Accounts-UI package**

Personally as a quick tool I am a big fan of the React Accounts-UI package https://atmospherejs.com/std/accounts-ui

It's easy to implement and has many React specific config options.

Check out 'Create your own styled version' to implement in Navbar at https://github.com/studiointeract/accounts-ui/blob/master/README.md

---

### **React with Kadira FlowRouter and ReactLayout**

For something within the Navbar, here is a stab with flow router.

From the Meteor Guide User/Authentication section:

> While a router is optional and the basic functionality will work without it, it’s also a good idea to pick a router integration:

For Navbar login (Not React Accounts-UI).

You need [Flowrouter](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/flow-router) and [Reactlayout](https://atmospherejs.com/kadira/react-layout)

**Routes**

We create 2 route [groups](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router#group-routes) which allow us to build auth logic into Flow router easily:

```
const publicRoutes = FlowRouter.group( { name: 'public' } );
  publicRoutes.route( '/login', { 
    name: 'login', 
    action() { 
      ReactLayout.render( App, { 
        yield: <Login /> }
       ); 
     } 
   }
 );

const authenticatedRoutes = FlowRouter.group( { name: 'authenticated' } );
  authenticatedRoutes.route( '/hidden', { 
    name: 'hidden', 
    action() { 
      ReactLayout.render( App, { 
        yield: <Hidden /> }
        ); 
      }
    }
 );
```

**App:**

You can modify this to suit your own setup. The approach here is to grab the [reactmeteordata](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) mixing which allows us to test if the user is logged or logging in. The isPublic function allows us to test if the user should be allowed on the current route. The rest should be self explanatory.

```
App = React.createClass({ 
  mixins: [ ReactMeteorData ],
  getMeteorData() { 
    return { 
      loggingIn: Meteor.loggingIn(), 
      hasUser: !!Meteor.user(),
      isPublic( route ) {
        let publicRoutes = [ 
          'login' 
        ];

        return publicRoutes.indexOf( route ) > -1; 
      }, 
      canView() { 
        return this.isPublic( FlowRouter.current().route.name ) || !!Meteor.user(); 
      } 
    }; 
  }, 
  loading() { 
    return <div className="loading"></div>; 
  }, 
  getView() { 
    return this.data.canView() ? this.props.yield : <Login />;
  },
  render() { 
   return <div className="app-root">
     <AppHeader hasUser={this.data.hasUser} />
       <div className="container">
         {this.data.loggingIn ? this.loading() : this.getView()} 
       </div> 
      </div>; 
    } 
  }
);
```

**Header:**

Nothing cosmic, we change the brandLink depending on user state. We then check hasUser (passed as a prop from the App component) to change which nav component to display.

```
AppHeader = React.createClass({ 
  mixins: [ ReactMeteorData ],
  getMeteorData() { 
    return { brandLink: !!Meteor.user() ? '/hidden' : '/login' }; }, 

    render() { 
      return ( <nav className="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
       <div className="container"> 
         <div className="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"><span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span className="icon-bar"></span> <span className="icon-bar"></span><span className="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
           <a className="navbar-brand" href={this.data.brandLink}>AuthExample</a>
         </div> 
         {this.props.hasUser ? <AuthenticatedNavigation /> : <PublicNavigation />} 
       </div> 
     </nav> ); 
    } 
  });
```

AuthenticatedNavigation component :

```
AuthenticatedNavigation = React.createClass({ 
  currentUserEmail() { 
    return Meteor.user().emails[0].address; 
  },

  logout( event ) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 

    return Meteor.logout( () =>
       FlowRouter.go( '/login' ) ); 
  },
  render() { 
    return <div id="navbar-collapse" className="collapse navbar-collapse"> 
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        <li className={FlowHelpers.currentRoute( 'hidden' )}><a href="/hidden">Hidden</a>
        </li> 
      </ul> 
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
        <li className="dropdown">
          <a href="#" className="user-profile-toggle dropdown-toggle clearfix" data-toggle="dropdown">{this.currentUserEmail()} <span className="caret"></span> 
          </a> 
          <ul className="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
            <li><a href="/preferences">Account Preferences</a></li> 
             <li className="logout" onClick={this.logout}><a href="#">Logout</a></li> 
          </ul> 
        </li> 
      </ul> 
    </div>;
    } 
 });
```

PublicNavigation Component:

```
PublicNavigation = React.createClass({ 
  render() { 
     return ( 
       <div id="navbar-collapse" className="collapse navbar-collapse"> 
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
          <li className={FlowHelpers.currentRoute( 'login' )}> 
           <a href={FlowHelpers.pathFor( 'login' )}>Login</a> 
         </li> 
       </ul>
     </div> ); 
    } 
  }
);
```

Look at https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/authentication-with-react-and-flow-router/ for more details.

Comment: How can I enable a navbar login feature with this?

Comment: Answer edited for Navbar. Check whitespace if copy and paste, I'm doing this on a phone!